# Agregar consecutivos "CR-0000052" a la base de datos

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigger

Deseo agregar un consecutivo cada vez qué se ingresan datos a una tabla factura. Es decir un autoincremental en el cúal contiene letras y números. Por lo cuál primero estoy creando Querys probando la funcionalidad. Pero tengo problemas con los if dentro del Query de postgreSQL.

```
   DECLARE
   rec record ;
   consecutivo varchar := 'CR-0000001';
   consecutivoNum varchar ;
   consecutivoLet varchar ;
   consecutivoNuevo varchar := 'CR-';
   numero integer := 0  ;
   BEGIN
       
       consecutivoLet := SPLIT_PART(consecutivo, '-', 1 );
       consecutivoNum := SPLIT_PART(consecutivo, '-', 2 );
       
       numero := consecutivoNum AS INTEGER ;
       RAISE NOTICE 'Consecutivo anterior %', numero ;
       numero := numero  + 1 ;
       
       IF numero < 10 THEN
           consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT(consecutivoLet, '000000', numero);
           
       ELSE IF numero < 100 THEN
           consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT(consecutivoNuevo, '00000', numero);
       ELSE IF numero < 1000 THEN
           consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT(consecutivoNuevo, '0000', numero);
       ELSE IF numero < 10000 THEN
           consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT(consecutivoNuevo, '000', numero);
       ELSE IF numero < 100000 THEN
           consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT(consecutivoNuevo, '00', numero);
       ELSE IF numero < 1000000 THEN
           consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT(consecutivoNuevo, '0', numero);
       ELSE IF numero < 10000000 THEN
           consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT(consecutivoNuevo, numero);   
       END IF
       


       RAISE NOTICE  '%',consecutivoNuevo ;
       
       
       
   END
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Por ahora estoy haciendo una prueba, en que ya tengo un consecutivo y separó las letras de los números con el simbolo '-', después incremento el número y lo concateno para obtener el nuevo consecutivo. El problema es qué los IF-ELSE statement estna generando un error.

````
LINE 23:  END
          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 578```


Gracias
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No veo la necesidad de los `IF`s en primer lugar, bastaría con un:

`CONCAT('CR-',RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000',numero),7))`

o similar

Comment: Gracias,  La solución es : **consecutivoNuevo := CONCAT('CR-', RIGHT(CONCAT('0000000', numero),7)); **